# Issues in splitting text using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Apologies for my poor understanding on the regex world. I'm trying to split a text using regex. Here's what I'm doing right now. Please consider the following string

```
String input = "Name:\"John Adam\"  languge:\"english\"  Date:\" August 2011\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\:\\\".*?\\\"\\s*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List keyValues = new LinkedList();
while(matcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
   keyValues.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(keyValues);
```

I get the right output, which is what I'm looking.

```
Name:"John Adam"  
languge:"english"  
Date:" August 2011"
```

Now, I'm struggling to make it a little generic. For e.g. if I add another pattern in the input string. I've added a new value Audience:(user) in a different pattern, i.e. " is replaced by ();

```
String input = "Name:\"John Adam\"  languge:\"english\"  Date:\" August 2011\"  Audience:(user)";
```

What'll be the generic pattern for this ? Sorry if this sounds too lame.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Remove most of those baskslashes - you don't need to escape quotes or colons (they are just another normal character)

Try this pattern:

```
".*?:[^\\w ].*?[^\\w ]\\s*"
```

It works for all non-word/space chars being a delimiter, works for your test case, and would work for `name:'foo'` etc

Comment: thanks for simplifying it, it does work for most of the cases, except if there's format like test:abc .

Comment: You would be better off changing the regex to capture the name and value each as a regex group: `"(.*?):[^\\w ](.*?)[^\\w ]\\s*"` then using `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` to access them directly

Answer (score 1):

You can always use OR operator `|`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\:\\\".*?\\\"\\s*)|(.*?\\:\\(.*?\\)\\s*)");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I should point out that regular expressions are NOT a magic bullet. By that I mean that while they can be incredibly flexible and useful in some cases they don't solve all problems of text matching (for instance parsing XML-like markup)

However, in the example you gave, you could use the `|` syntax to specify an alternate pattern to match. An example might be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\:(\\\".*?\\\"|\\(.*?\\))\\s*");
```

This section in parentheses: `(\\\".*?\\\"|\\(.*?\\))` can be thought of as: find a pattern that matches `\\\".*?\\\"` or `\\(.*?\\)` (and remember what the backslashes mean - they are escape characters.

Note though that this approach, while flexible, requires you to add a specific case quite literally so it's not truly generic in the absolute sense.

*NOTE*

To better illustrate what I meant by not being able to craft a truly generic solution, here's a more generic pattern that you could use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\:[\\\"(]{1,2}.*?[\\\")]{1,2}\\s*");
```

The pattern above uses character classes and it's more generic but while it will match your examples, it will also match things like:  `blah:\stuff\` or `blah:"stuff"` or even hybrids like `blah:\"stuff)` or worse `blah:((stuff""`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I completely understand you viewpoint, though it fits this specific scenario, its not truly generic.

Comment: Yep @Shamik - you could make it a little more generic but that would have to be at the expense of potentially matching something you wouldn't want to match (I'll update my answer with an example)